# devise password recovery under multitenancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-recoverable

An application runs multiple third level domains, which are accessible by an instance variable `@site`.

However, that cannot be set for an environment configuration file   `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`

The Devise repository provides no indication as to how this is achieved within the devise framework, possibly delegating this to Rails functions.

How can a materially multi-tenant application determine the url for links in mailers?